# How to adjust year in date if it's empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a database which stores a diary of events (pretty similar to how facebook works) these can be for a specific single date, or recurring each year. For example I may have a wedding on 1st June 2013 and a birthday on the 4th May every year. I am trying to extract a list of all events that are occurring in the next year, in order of when they will happen.

```
id u_id title           event_day  event_month  event_year
1   1   Wedding         22         02           2013
2   1   Jan Birthday    1          1            
3   1   May Birthday    04         5
```

Using this query, I can fill in the current year, but then if an event has already occurred (such as 'jan birthday' in the data above it needs to be the current year plus one that is add:

```
SELECT title, IF(event_year = '', YEAR(CURDATE()), event_year) AS ev_year,
event_day, event_month 
FROM `events`
```

returns:

```
title           ev_year event_day  event_month  
Wedding         2013    22         02
Jan Birthday    2014    1          1
May Birthday    2014    04         5
```

Thanks

Comment: I was referring to how they pull it out, not store it

Comment: Do you have control over the data? or is this facebooks? I think there is an elegent solution for this. I might have a much simpler solution not seperating the month, day, and year...

Comment: If it's confusing you then just ignore the analogy to Facebook. I am hoping to display a diary for the upcoming year in order of which events are next.

Comment: @shawn, yes I do have control, I would have used a timestamp but couldn't given the fact that some events don't have a year and therefore can't have a timestamp

Comment: @Al_ i will give you a solution if you can alter the table to just hold the date as one field. Give me a moment.

Comment: [MySQL has `DATE`field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html), use it.

Comment: @Al_ Ok but you could just put last year into it. Give me am oment to write something up.

Comment: but how would I then differentiate between one time events like a wedding that have a year and a birthday that happens every year starting on a fixed year?

Comment: @moonwave - how should I create date field without a year?

Comment: You just store the first occurrence of the event [i.e. w/ year], then the period of recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Would recommend to store in a single datetime column and just flag recurring events - you can still calc on them. As a benefit you will even know how old the peoaple are :)

But with your current table:

```
SELECT title, IF(event_year = '', 
IF(event_day < DAY(CURDATE()) AND event_month = MONTH(CURDATE()) OR event_month <
MONTH(CURDATE()), YEAR(CURDATE())+1, YEAR(CURDATE())), event_year) AS ev_year,
event_day, event_month 
FROM `events`
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but I now need to restrict it to only show events within the next year, which I guess is where not using a date format falls down as I can't do a direct comparison on the 3 separate fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
title             event_date 
Wedding           2013-22-02
Jan Birthday      2014-01-01
May Birthday      2014-04-05
Als Birthday      ?-11-15 //(We know birthdays happen yearly so we can calculate back on this in SQL)
Jane Doe Wedding  ?-1-2 //(We might not know the year yet. So we can handle this in 2 ways. Dont enter the event into your planner until the couple tells you the date (or mails you the date), OR you can treat the date the same as a birthday so you get alerted this year)
```

Ok so what you want to do is do date comparison; let mysql handle this logic with something like:

> SELECT id FROM events WHERE CURDATE() > event_date; //this gets you all
>   expired events

So now you can update the year by doing date interval such as:

> UPDATE events SET event_date = DATE_ADD(event_date,INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
>   WHERE id IN (#numbers_from_above_query#); //this will add a year to your
>   date field

Now for when you don't know the date you can simply do

> DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) //this will subtract from the
>   current year so that you are 1 year behind. You can use this to
>   populate your data. In this way the first query should catch that a
>   birthday has already passed.

Comment: Let me know if you have questions here or need me to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the post, for this to work do I need to set up a cron job to update all events in the database that are in the database (and set to recur annually) each day?

Comment: It depends on your needs. I mean you can do it daily OR you can have this run as you login to your app. If its the first thing to run (the update) then you should be ok. The catch with running it when you run your app is a few birthdays may have been missed. Does that make sense? For example if you get alerts in the day of an event then you want a cron, but if you are more or less looking forward to next month and do a query basically saying get me all items that happen a month from now; then you only need it to run once.